# Query String issue when it contains Arabic text

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

I am trying to get query string from url With this code:

```
this.site_query = Request.Url.Query;
```

When I have get url:

> [http://localhost:1751/ar/search?q=سيارة](http://localhost:1751/ar/search?q=%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9)

It gives me blow output in code:

> http://localhost:1751/ar/Search?q=%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9&Location=%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%A7,Abha

But I need Arabic text that I send in query string. When query string contains   text in English then in c# it is correct.

Comment: That *is* in arabic (or at least it looks like it as I don't understand it) but is URL encoded.

Comment: how i get text that is in url

Comment: Do you mean `Request.QueryString["q"]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arabic QueryString problem (???? in the value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091550/arabic-querystring-problem-in-the-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use 
string name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(txtName.Text.Trim()));
    string technology = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(ddlTechnology.SelectedItem.Value));

for encoding url.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with the second URL you have shown in your answer, it's just being [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) due to the limitations of what characters are allowed in URLs.

If you wish to get parts of the query string in code, you can use code like this:

```
var query = Request.QueryString["q"];
```

Additionally, if you are building your URLs in code, you should always [URL encode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) and values that may contain non standard characters:

```
var urlEncodedValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(someValue);
```

Comment: but i have not only q in my quarry string in another case there are more then one quarry strings are avaliable

Comment: Well replace `q` with the other names. For example `Request.QueryString["Location"]` will also give you a value from your second URL.

Answer (score 4):

As others said already: it's an encoded URL. You can decode with

```
var decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
```

or

```
var decodedUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url);
```

Is that what you need? If not, show us your expected output.